# How to redirect registered users to their homepage using yii2

Tags: php, authentication, yii2

I'm a front-end designer, and to be honest, i'm still new to Yii2.

I have to create two home page. One for the non-registered users and one for registered users.

I am able to create a homepage for non-registered users, the one that is in `site/index`.

Now, I am having trouble with regards to routing registered users to their own homepage. I have read the docs on yii2 documentation but it's quite confusing for a newbie like me.

If a registered user logs in, i'd like to show them their own home page which is on the `app/index`. But it's not working for me.

here's the code:

```
public function actionLogin()
{

    $this->layout='login-main';

    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        $this->layout='app-main';
        return $this->redirect( array('app/index') );
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
         $this->layout='app-main'; 
         return $this->redirect( array('app/index') );
    } else {
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

When I implement this code, I get this error. (please see attached image)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2a43j.jpg)

can you let me know if this is right? or any other suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: I suspect the login is not working, can you debug and let me know ? if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) - code works after this line ?

Answer (score 0):

create AppController and
this is the code that u should redirect logged in user to their private area

```
if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {

    return $this->redirect( ['/app'] );
}
```

and the layout of the logged in user (app controller) 
should set in app controller

```
 $this->layout='app-main';
```

Comment: how do I let the view app/index know that it will be AppController and not the SiteController that handles it?

Comment: use `if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {}` in view to know which user is loggedin and whose not

Answer (score 0):

In login action write the below code

```
if ( !Yii::$app->user->isGuest )
{
  return $this->goHome();
}
```

Comment: I've done this before but it just shows me the index for the non-registered users.

Comment: are u using user management module for user registration and login ??

Comment: if yes then in add this to AuthController, loginAction() if ( !Yii::$app->user->isGuest )
{
  return $this->redirect('/site/registered');
}else{return $this->redirect('/site/not-registered');}   Now add 2 layout file to your inside app/views/layout like register.php and notregister.php.  Then create the about 2 action in siteController.php as actionRegister(){ $this->layout = 'register' ;$this->render('page u want to show regisred user');}  and actionNotregister(){ $this->layout = 'notregister'; $this->render('page for non registerd user');}

Comment: Yeah, I have applied the redirection and got it. :) I cant cast a vote on this comment but just letting you know i've applied the redirection..

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is create two alias of url once for guest user and second for registred user then you need to check on logiin action that user is guest or not. Accordingly you can redirect with url.